# twitter bot on pythonanywhere runs but tweets does not show on twitter search

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, pythonanywhere

I made a twitter bot that tweets every 15 minutes when I run the bot locally it works fine but when I run on pythonanywhere server it updates the twitter status but the tweets does not show up in Twitter search.
I post the tweets from .txt file which contains some links. Please help me!

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep
from credentials3 import *

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

my_file=open('post.txt','r')
file_lines=my_file.readlines()
my_file.close()

def tweet():
    for line in file_lines:
        try:
             if line != '\n':
                 api.update_status(status=line)
                 print(line)
                 sleep(720)
             else:
                pass
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.reason)
            sleep(2)

tweet()
```

Comment: Is it showing in your account in tweets?

Comment: Yes it is showing in my account tweets but it does not show in twitter search

Comment: Is this a new account? Are you posting a lot of similar content? Does this show up in the Twitter web search, the API search, or not at all?

Comment: No, I am not posting the similar content even if I just add a single string through pythonanywhere it does not show up in twitter web search or API search at all. I made this account in July https://twitter.com/blogchef3

Comment: If the tweets are showing up in your account but not search, it's likely to be something to do with Twitter's search algorithm -- perhaps they weight tweets from new accounts lower until the account has more than a certain number of followers, or something like that?